# My Pi can boot but extremely hot. HELP!

Tags: gpio, boot, temperature

After trying the GPIO, my PI cannot not boot. Few weeks later, the polyfuse seems recovered and it can be boot.

But the CPU is very hot and reach 80C. The USB port is not work and the PI is abnormal.

When I connect it to power supply to long time, the polyfuse again failed.

I am using Model B. Please help.

Comment: Sounds like this baby is broken.

Comment: try an alternate power supply, make sure everything is disconnected and use the testing instructions found here http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting_power_problems

Comment: TP1 and TP2 : ~3.7V. difference between polyfuse :~0.3V

Answer (score 1):

If I had more rep i'd ask more questions to help better understand what has happened, but its plausible that you may have a broken pi, sorry mate.

Hope everything works out.

Comment: I tested my SD card and power supply by another PI. They work  as well as before.

Comment: What about your original board, i mean usually an ac adapter is fine, the sd card is expected to fail but not massively. Maybe it was just your old pi with hardware problems possibly?